# Not able to handle UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown for view Controller for iPad

Tags: ipad, uiinterfaceorientation

In my iPad app i have tabbarController for firstView, for tabbarController  i added button when we press that, one viewcontroller will come.
My problem is when i am trying to turn that viewcontroller in PortraitUpsideDown, it was not comming to PortraitUpsideDown. 
The code i use in that viewController is

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
// Overriden to allow any orientation.
return(interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
```

// return YES;
}

}

Can anyone tell me that What mistake i made or anything is there to add.
Thank u.